# Как сделать подзапрос в связанную модель Django с фильтрацией

Tags: python, django

У меня есть 2 модели:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length=255)


class Verification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

У модели верификации поле статус хранит в себе статус верификации пользователя (в частности мне нужен статус "accepted")

Я хочу из модели юзера сделать запрос с аннотацией поля `accepted_verification`, которое будет в себе содержать либо True, если статус "accepted", либо False, если какой-либо другой. Как лучше всего сделать такой запрос?

Comment: Может стоит переопределить модель пользователя и добавить к ней просто поле verification?
Вот ссылка на пример: https://evileg.com/ru/post/611/